# R Error: Coloring Graphs According to Values Within a Matrix

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language.

I am trying to make a 3 Dimensional Graph between variables "x, y and w", and color this graph according to values of "z" :

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

X <- seq(0,3.1,0.1)
Y <- seq(0,3.1,0.1)
W <- seq(0,3.1,0.1)
DF <- expand.grid(X,Y, W)

#Compute variable for colors
DF$Z <- sin(DF$Var1) + cos(DF$Var2) + sin(DF$Var3)

#make a matrix of color values
Mat <- matrix(DF$Z,nrow = 32)

#make a matrix for z values

Mat2 <- matrix(rep(c(1:16,16:1),32),nrow=32)

#plot
    plot_ly(y=~Y,x=X,  z=~W) %>%  
      add_surface(surfacecolor=~Mat)
```

But this produces an error:

```
Error: `z` must be a numeric matrix
```

Can anyone please show me how to fix this problem?

Thanks

**Note:** For some reason, the following code works:

```
X <- seq(0,3.1,0.1)
Y <- seq(0,3.1,0.1)
DF <- expand.grid(X,Y)

#Compute variable for colors
DF$Z <- sin(DF$Var1) + cos(DF$Var2)

#make a matrix of color values
Mat <- matrix(DF$Z,nrow = 32)

#make a matrix for z values
Mat2 <- matrix(rep(c(1:16,16:1),32),nrow=32)

plot_ly(y=~Y,x=X,  z=~Mat2) %>%  
    add_surface(surfacecolor=~Mat)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data are essentially *points on a line* in three dimensions (`X`, `Y`, `W`) so it's not clear what surface you want to plot. `add_surface` expects `z`-values to be a 32x32 matrix (since `X` and `Y` have 32 entries each) but you supply the vector `W` in your (first) call, hence the error. In your second attempt, you supply `Mat2` which is a matrix with appropriate dimensions. Also note that the `surfacecolor` needs to be 32x32 matrix, too.

So set up the `W` matrix, compute the color matrix `colors` (I use a matrix of ones for simplicity below),

```r
W <- matrix(rep(1, 32^2), ncol = 32)
grid <- data.frame(W = c(W), X = rep(X, each = 32), Y = Y)
colors <- 
  matrix(
    mapply(function(x,y,z) sin(x)+cos(y)+sin(z), grid$X, grid$Y, grid$W), 
    nrow = 32, byrow = T
  )
```

and plot:

```r
plot_ly(y = ~Y, x = ~X,  z = ~W) %>%  
  add_surface(surfacecolor = ~colors)
```

[image]

**Edit**

To plot `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, suitably transform `DF$Z` to a 32x32 matrix:

```r
DF <- expand.grid(X,Y)
DF$Z <- sin(DF$Var1) + cos(DF$Var2)
Z <- matrix(DF$Z, nrow = 32)

plot_ly(y = ~Y, x = ~X, z=~Z) %>%  
  add_surface()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Suppose I just want to make a graph of X, Y and Z (ignore W) - can you please show me how to do this?

Comment: Why is "32" chosen?

Comment: 32 is the length of your `X` and `Y` vectors. You can check this using `length(X)`. I've edited my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I tried to slightly modify your answer - can you please tell me if the code below makes sense? (semicolon ; indicates new line of code)

Comment: n <- 50;
my_grid <- expand.grid(i1 = 1:n, i2 = 1:n);
my_grid$final_value = with(my_grid, sin(i1) + cos(i2) );

Z <- matrix(my_grid$final_value, nrow = 50)
plot_ly(y = ~my_grid$i1, x = ~my_grid$i2, z=~Z) %>%  
    add_surface()

Comment: The code looks fine. Note that `1:n` results in a grid that might be to coarse for `add_surface`. Would be better to provide a finer grid (e.g., using `seq()`as you have done above.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! In the end - I think I was able to understand everything. The number of rows in matrix "Z" has to be "cleanly divisible" by the total number of rows in "DF"

Comment: X <- seq(0,100,1);
Y <- seq(0,100,1);

DF <- expand.grid(X,Y);
DF$Z <- sin(DF$Var1) + cos(DF$Var2);
Z <- matrix(DF$Z, nrow = 100);

plot_ly(y = ~Y, x = ~X, z=~Z) %>%  
    add_surface()

Comment: For a while, I was having this problem where the hover text and legend within the plot was returning illogical values, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68520321/understanding-hover-text-in-plotly