# Directly Plotting Mathematical Functions in R

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language.

In a previous question that I asked ([Understanding 3D traces in Plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68520321/understanding-3d-traces-in-plotly) and [R: Evaluating and Plotting Functions Over a Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68507481/r-evaluating-and-plotting-functions-over-a-grid)), I learned how to plot mathematical functions by first evaluating the mathematical function at different points, then by plotting these points on a 3D grid, and finally "interpolating" a 3D surface over these points:

```
# set seed for reproducibility 
#load libraries
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

#create more data
n <- 50
my_grid <- expand.grid(i1 = 1:n, i2 = 1:n)
my_grid$final_value = with(my_grid, sin(i1) + cos(i2) )

#make plot
plot_ly(data = my_grid,  x=~i1, y=~i2, z=~final_value, type='mesh3d', intensity = ~final_value, colors = colorRamp(c("blue", "grey", "red")))
```

[image]

I am trying to use this same approach to plot the following function (https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Test_functions_for_optimization&oldid=1030693803, https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Test_functions_for_optimization&oldid=1030693803#/media/File:ConstrTestFunc03.png) :

[image]

**I first defined the function:**

```
  my_function <- function(x,y) {
    
    final_value = (1 - x)^2 + 100*((y - x^2)^2)
     
    }
```

**Then, I defined the "grid":**

```
input_1 <- seq(-1.5, 1.5,0.1)
input_2 <- seq(-1.5, 1.5,0.1)


my_grid <- data.frame(input_1, input_2)
my_grid$final_value =   (1 - input_1)^2 + 100*((input_2 - input_1^2)^2)
```

**Then, I tried to plot this function:**

```
 x <- my_grid$input_1
y <- my_grid$input_2

z <- matrix(my_grid$final_value, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(y)) # proper matrix & dimensions

plot_ly(x = x, y = y, z = z) %>% add_surface()
```

**My Problem:** The final result does not look similar to the result from the Wikipedia page:

[image]

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong? Is there an easier way to do this?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not actually creating a grid, you are creating a single vector of equal x, y points and running your formula on that, so your matrix is wrong (every column will be the same due to it being repeated). The easiest fix is to run `outer` on your function to evaluate it at every pair of input 1 and input 2:

```r
z <- outer(input_1, input_2, my_function)

plot_ly(x = input_1, y = input_2, z = z) %>% add_surface()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! If you have time, could you please show me how to add "contours" to this plot? I tried the code below and it does not seem to be working:

Comment: fig <- plot_ly(
    type = 'surface',
    contours = list(
        x = list(show = TRUE, start = 1.5, end = 2, size = 0.04, color = 'white'),
        z = list(show = TRUE, start = 0.5, end = 0.8, size = 0.05)),
    x = ~input_1,
    y = ~input_2,
    z = ~z)
fig <- fig %>% layout(
    scene = list(
        xaxis = list(nticks = 20),
        zaxis = list(nticks = 4),
        camera = list(eye = list(x = 0, y = -1, z = 0.5)),
        aspectratio = list(x = .9, y = .8, z = 0.2)))

fig

Comment: I adapted the code from here: https://plotly.com/r/3d-surface-plots/

Comment: I posted my progress over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71313167/adding-contour-lines-to-3d-plots Thank you so much!