# Adding Contour Lines to 3D Plots

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I made the following 3 Dimensional Plot using the "plotly" library:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

  my_function <- function(x,y) {
    
    final_value = (1 - x)^2 + 100*((y - x^2)^2)
     
    }

input_1 <- seq(-1.5, 1.5,0.1)
input_2 <- seq(-1.5, 1.5,0.1)

z <- outer(input_1, input_2, my_function)

plot_ly(x = input_1, y = input_2, z = z) %>% add_surface()
```

[image]

I am now trying to add "contour lines" to the above plot as shown below: https://plotly.com/r/3d-surface-plots/

[image]

I am trying to adapt the code from the "plotly website" to make these contours, but I am not sure how to do this:

**Graph 1:**

```
# This might have worked?
fig <- plot_ly(z = ~z) %>% add_surface(
  contours = list(
    z = list(
      show=TRUE,
      usecolormap=TRUE,
      highlightcolor="#ff0000",
      project=list(z=TRUE)
      )
    )
  )
fig <- fig %>% layout(
    scene = list(
      camera=list(
        eye = list(x=1.87, y=0.88, z=-0.64)
        )
      )
  )
```

[image]

**Graph 2:**

```
# I don't think this worked?
fig <- plot_ly(
  type = 'surface',
  contours = list(
    x = list(show = TRUE, start = 1.5, end = 2, size = 0.04, color = 'white'),
    z = list(show = TRUE, start = 0.5, end = 0.8, size = 0.05)),
  x = ~x,
  y = ~y,
  z = ~z)
fig <- fig %>% layout(
    scene = list(
      xaxis = list(nticks = 20),
      zaxis = list(nticks = 4),
      camera = list(eye = list(x = 0, y = -1, z = 0.5)),
      aspectratio = list(x = .9, y = .8, z = 0.2)))

fig
```

[image]

**Can someone please show me how to correctly adapt these above codes?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The contour lines are on your plots, but may not be super visible due to the parameters in the `contours.z` list. Here's how you can tweak the contour lines to fit your needs:

```
fig <- plot_ly(z = ~z) %>% add_surface(
  contours = list(
    z = list(
      show = TRUE,
      # project=list(z=TRUE)       # (don't) project contour lines to underlying plane
      # usecolormap = TRUE,        # (don't) use surface color scale for contours
      color = "white",             # set contour color
      width = 1,                   # set contour thickness
      highlightcolor = "#ff0000",  # highlight contour on hover
      start = 0,                   # include contours from z = 0...
      end = 1400,                  # to z = 1400...
      size = 100                   # every 100 units

    )
  )
)
```

[image]

You can draw lines along the other dimensions by passing lists to `x` or `y`. (Per follow-up question from OP) you can change the surface color scale using `colorscale`, either specifying one of the [named colorscale options](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/5bc25b490702e5ed61265207833dbd58e8ab27f1/src/components/colorscale/scales.js) or building your own. Example:

```
fig <- plot_ly(z = ~z) %>% add_surface(
  colorscale = "Picnic",
  contours = list(
    x = list(show=TRUE, color="#a090b0", width=2, start=0, end=30, size=7.5),
    y = list(show=TRUE, color="#a090b0", width=2, start=0, end=30, size=7.5),
    z = list(show=TRUE, color="#a090b0", width=2, start=0, end=1400, size=300)
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Zephryl: Thank you so much for your answer! Just a question - suppose you want to play around with the colors - are there other color schemes that are easily available? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob Sure, see built-in colorscales [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/5bc25b490702e5ed61265207833dbd58e8ab27f1/src/components/colorscale/scales.js). Example in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot to save your original answer... can you please include the previous and the new one? Thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob The only change I made was to add `colorscale = "Picnic"` and futz with the contour `width` and `color` args a bit. But If you'd like you can see the previous version in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71346824/revisions).

Answer (score 7):

You were almost there.
The contours on `z` should be defined according to `min`-`max` values of `z`:

```
plot_ly(x = input_1, y = input_2, z = z,
        contours = list(
          z = list(show = TRUE, start = round(min(z),-2),
                                end = round(max(z),-2), 
                                size = 100))) %>% 
        add_surface()
```

[image]

or automatically set by `plotly` :

```
plot_ly(x = input_1, y = input_2, z = z,
        colors = 'Oranges',
        contours = list(
          z = list(show = TRUE))) %>% 
  add_surface()
```

[image]

Comment: @ Waldi: Thank you so much for your answer! Just a question - suppose you want to play around with the colors - are there other color schemes that are easily available? Thank you so much!

Comment: You could use the `colorscale` argument in the call to `plotly`,  for example `plot_ly(x = input_1, y = input_2, z = z,
        colorscale = list(c(0, 1), c("green", "orange")),
        contours = list(...)`

Comment: Or use the `colors` argument with a [RColorBrewer Palette](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/38-rcolorbrewers-palettes.html), for example `colors='Oranges'`, see my edit above

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot to save your original answer... can you please include the previous and the new one? Thank you so much!

Comment: All the answers / modifications can be viewed by clicking on the [edited x hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71346792/revisions) link below the answer. I just added a `colors` argument.